# Adding child nodes in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm making a shortcut program for my daily games I do play. It's sorta like mobile phone folders work just so that you know what I mean.

So far I've come to:

```
    private void addGame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name      = string.Empty;
        string game_path = string.Empty;
        string icon_path = string.Empty;


        OpenFileDialog ofdGamePath = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofdGamePath.Title = "Choose the game...";

        OpenFileDialog ofdIconPath = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofdIconPath.Title = "Choose the icon...";

        if (ofdGamePath.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            game_path = ofdGamePath.FileName;
        }

        if (ofdIconPath.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            icon_path = ofdIconPath.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Where I currently stuck is the saving to XML path. While on my research I found alot "overkill" solutions which absolutely not fit my scope.

My games.xml looks like the following:

```
    <Games>
      <game name="" path="" icon="" />
    </Games>
```

Also reading the file isn't a problem either. Here's the code I use for reading it:

```
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\" + args[1]);
        XmlNodeList elemList = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("game");

        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            string name = elemList[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
            string game_path = elemList[i].Attributes["path"].Value;
            string icon_path = elemList[i].Attributes["icon"].Value;
        }
```

Could anyone direct me into the right direction on how to simply save that one line of XML? Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found what I needed!

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\" + args[1]);
        XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("Applications");

        if (el != null)
        {
            XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("app");
            elem.SetAttribute("name", "name online game here");
            elem.SetAttribute("path", "123123123");
            elem.SetAttribute("icon", "test");

            el.AppendChild(elem);
        }

        doc.Save(Application.StartupPath + @"\" + args[1]);
```

Resulting in:

```
  <app name="name online game here" path="123123123" icon="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       using (var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create("MyFile.xml"))elemList[i].WriteTo(writer);
```

Comment: Uh. I don't think you can follow. What I want to achieve is saving the three strings in an XML file with the node being <game> and as attributes the name, path and icon (the strings).

Comment: It's still the same answer, although i edited it now to use your element node, whereas before i used the document node.

Comment: Found a way. :) Thanks anyways!

Comment: Err, my first answer and second answer did that. You are saving the entire document with the Save method which is fair enough but intellisense would have shown that far quicker than writing up the  question.  You used Load, naturally you'd use Save.  The question implies you wanted just to save a Game node and not the whole document - "that one line".  Anyway...